# git diff --numstat with --name-status

Tags: git, git-diff

Is there any way to get the output of running `git diff --numstat` and `git diff --name-status` combined in one run?
My problem is that if I am using only `--numstat` then I don't know whether there were just added some new lines to a file or if the file is completely new. When using `--name-status` I get the information if the file is new or not but the stats about the line modifications are missing.

Currently my workaround is running both commands separately and then merging that output by a PowerShell script but as the repo is rather big I would like to have the needed output in the first place. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can combine the `--numstat` and the `--summary` flags;

```
git diff --numstat --summary
```

Note that a new file cannot be in the "unstaged" area; so suppose you used "git add" and "git rm", then your git status will look like this:

```
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       new file:   b
#       deleted:    a
```

then using

```
git diff --cached --numstat --summary
```

will give you:

```
540  0   b
0    3   a
 create mode 100644 b
 delete mode 100644 a
```

**NOTE** : you can use the `--numstat` and the `--summary` flags in combination with `git diff`, `git diff --cached`, `git show` and probably other commands.

Comment: Thanks!
I think --numstat with --summary seems to be feasible but to be honest, I hoped to get the data for each file in a single line (or to specify a custom format altogether) so that the output format would not change and the parsing script would be simpler :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use some different flags to achieve it:

```
git log --stat --summary
```

Here is a screenshot of this command. You have all the information per file and summary after each commit.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I think it won't work for two separate commits and I am still not able to tell whether a file was added or simply had only insertions

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--diff-filter=A` option to get only new files and `--diff-filter=a` to get other changes:

```sh
git diff --numstat --diff-filter=A
git diff --numstat --diff-filter=a
```